# Would compiler optimization remove try/catch block if catch does nothing?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, error-handling, c++20

I am working with code that has a lot of `try` `catch` blocks in but most cases the `catch` blocks do nothing. As in the code below `fib` function is throwing `invalid_argument` exception. The function call in `main` is in the `try` block but the `catch` block does not do anything, except catching the exception.

I am wondering if the compiler might trim away this kind of exception handling during code optimization, or not?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>


// Declaration for Wmissing-declarations flag
int fib(int);

int fib(int n)
{
    if (n < 0)
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid argument");
        }
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return n;
    
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int _number;
    std::cin >> _number;
    try
    {
        std::cout << fib(_number) << std::endl;
    }
    catch(const std::invalid_argument & e)
    {
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling above code with most (all I know) flags turned on, as below, does not show any warning.

```
g++ -o except exceptions.cxx -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wdisabled-optimization -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wnoexcept -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wsign-conversion -Wsign-promo -Wstrict-null-sentinel -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wswitch-default -Wundef -Werror -Wno-unused
```

Comment: The fact that there is a catch ensures that the exception is caught. Otherwise it would immediately terminate this function and probably many other functions and quite like cause termination of the program. It would end up with the program return non zero value - an error code information outside users that an error occurred in the program. However, these are caught and 0 is returned.

Comment: The compiler can't remove the `catch` as an optimization because this would change the behavior of the program. Except for very few and specific cases, optimizations are never allows to change the observable behavior. It also can't remove the `throw` because the function `fib` can't be allowed to `return` if `n < 0`.

Comment: A perfect compiler could be allowed to "rewrite" your program to have the same observable behavior without using `throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid argument");` but this would necessarily be imperceptible to you (in terms of behavior). So the real question is why specifically do you care whether or not the exception is optimized? How would you know the difference? This may be an XY problem.

Comment: At a minimum the compiler *must* unwind the stack. Given `fib` has two temporaries just in the recursive calls that must be unwound and the compiler doesn't know what stack depth `fib` will throw from, that alone precludes removal. https://godbolt.org/z/v37n6rxba

Comment: The premise of the question is wrong: an empty `try...catch` block does not do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I am wondering if the compiler might trim away this kind of exception handling during code optimization, or not?*

**TL;DR:** No, a compiler **cannot** and **must not** optimize away such exception handling.

---

As [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69195593/would-compiler-optimization-remove-try-catch-block-if-catch-does-nothing#comment122299953_69195593), an *empty* `catch` block is ***not*** the same as not having `try ... catch` blocks.

In your example, although there is no code actually *executed* in the `catch` block, the exception thrown when a negative number is passed to the `fib` function **is still caught by that block**. At that point, the `catch` block is *conceptually* entered, then exited pretty swiftly – passing control (silently) to the code immediately following that empty block.

There will also be some [(necessary) stack unwinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69195593/would-compiler-optimization-remove-try-catch-block-if-catch-does-nothing/69228948#comment122299636_69195593), and possibly other 'remedial' actions, performed when that `catch` block is invoked; thus, even such an empty `catch` block will *still actually catch* the relevant exceptions (specified as its arguments).

So, for your code (as-is), entering a test value of `-3` will result in normal, successful program termination. On my Windows console (invoked from Visual Studio), I see this:

```
-3

C:\SGGCode.exe (process 2888) exited with code 0.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

However, if I remove the `try..catch` block, giving the following `main` (leaving everything else untouched):

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int _number;
    std::cin >> _number;
    std::cout << fib(_number) << std::endl; // Removed try...catch
    return 0;
}
```

Then, when I run the program and give the same input, I get this uncaught exception error:

```
-3

C:\SGGCode.exe (process 2420) exited with code -1073740791.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

(Note that `-1073740791` is `0xc00004096`, which is an [uncaught exception error](https://www.minitool.com/news/0xc0000409.html).)

---

To make things a *bit* clearer, try adding a line like the following, immediately before the `return 0;` line in your `main`:

```cpp
    std::cout << "See - I'm still here!" << std::endl;
```

With your empty `catch`, that will execute; without it, the program will crash before it can get there.